# Installing Extension Ctrl+S Need Help

Tags: extension

There is an EE extension (Ctrl+S) I want to install, but when I download it, it is just a php file, with no ReadMe file as to where to install it.

I am stuck, I don’t know where to put this, to make it work. I know I am missing something basic, can someone tell me what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All kinds of add-ons should be put on their own folders inside `system/expressionengine/third_party/`.

The [info on installing plugins](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#installation) can be useful.

Pay attention that the name of the folder should be the same as the add-on without the prefix:

```
no_follow/pi.no_follow.php
```

Extensions also need to be enabled on [Control Panel > Add-ons > Extensions](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/add-ons/extension_manager.html).

Comment: Its just a file named ext.cri_s.php and I created a directory call /ctri_save/. Then put it in the  /third_party/ directory. It did  not show up in the Add-Ons section of the admin.

Comment: The name of the folder should be the same as the file - so try cri_s as the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this plugin : https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ctrls

I have used this before. the file you get is called `ext.ctrl_s.php`, and you should install it here `/system/expressionengine/third_party/ctrl_s/ext.ctrl_s.php`.

I've just installed this on EE 2.10.1 to test and it works fine. AS mentioned you need to goto `Add-Ons > Extensions` and 'Install' it.

Of course, I've done nothing but expand on Robson's answer above, except I've gone and got the extension for myself to check (assuming I've referred to the right one!). Once you get it working, make sure you mark Robson's answer as correct!